# How do I use tensoflow frozen graph for visualizing its feature maps?

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

**I am having tensoflow frozen graph (.pb). I want to visualize the hidden layer output (feature maps) given by that graph from an image. Is there any way to do it?**

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Probably the best place to start is tensorflow's native way to visualize network infromation, `tensorboard`.